# DRF: Programmatically get default choice from TextChoices field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Our site is a Vue frontend / DRF backend. In a `serializer.validate()` method, I need to programmatically determine which option from a `TextChoices` class has been specified as the default value for a model field.

TextChoices class (abbreviated example):

```
class PaymentMethod(models.TextChoices):
    BANK_TRANSFER = 'Bank Transfer'
    CREDIT_CARD = 'Credit Card'
    PAYPAL = 'PayPal'
    OTHER = 'Other'
```

The model:

```
class InvoicePayment(CommonFieldsModelMixin,
                     StatusFieldModelMixin,
                     models.Model):

    ...other fields omitted...
    payment_method = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Method'),
        choices=PaymentMethod.choices,
        default=PaymentMethod.OTHER,
    )
    payment_method_other = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Payment Method Other'),
        default='',
    )
```

Our users are able to bypass the frontend and post directly to the API, which means they may omit fields from the POST data - either from negligence or because the fields have default values.  For the above model, though, `payment_method_other` is required only if `payment_method` is "Other". That check is done in the `serializer.validate()` method.

If "Other" is selected on a form in the frontend, there's no problem because that value is present in `validated_data` passed to the `validate()` method. But if a user posts directly to the API and omits `payment_method`, the default value process is done at the database level (more or less), after the `validate()` method has executed.

To keep it DRY, and to avoid having mismatched code if the default is changed in the future, I don't want to hard-code the default of "Other" in the `validate()` method.  Instead, I want to access the field definition info (meta data?) and programmatically determine the default that was defined on the model.

Comment: I've added an answer about a way to determine the default of a field. But from what I understand about your explanation on the serializer, you are unable to handle the case where `payment_method` is omitted? That can still be checked in the validate by checking if the field is there or not right?

Comment: @bdbd, correct. If I don't find ```payment_metod``` in ```validated_data```, I know I need to supply the same default that *would be* supplied because it is defined on the model (which I can now do by way of the very simple solution in your answer; Thanks). Then if it happens to be "Other", it will pass/fail the validation just as if the user entered it.

Comment: Ok it's clear now. I was just thinking when it is omitted, you can do the default processing as if `Other` is there as `payment_method` and you don't need to set it explicitly because the db will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this without much hacking around is to define the default as a property of the model like this:

```
class InvoicePayment(CommonFieldsModelMixin,
                     StatusFieldModelMixin,
                     models.Model):

    DEFAULT_PAYMENT_METHOD = PaymentMethod.OTHER

    ...other fields omitted...
    payment_method = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Method'),
        choices=PaymentMethod.choices,
        default=DEFAULT_PAYMENT_METHOD,
    )
    payment_method_other = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Payment Method Other'),
        default='',
    )
```

Then you can just access the default easily through the model:

```
InvoicePayment.DEFAULT_PAYMENT_METHOD
```