# DRF: Set ChoiceField default programmatically from DB query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570115/drf-programmatically-get-default-choice-from-textchoices-field) about setting the default value of a TextChoices field on a model. Now I'm taking it to the next level.

I've moved the choices settings from the model to the serializer `ChoiceField`. The site is Django/DRF/django_tenants backend with Vue frontend. I want the front/backends to be using the same set of choices and, just as important, the same default values. So I created an OptionGroup table. Here are two sample rows from that table (some options omitted):

```
{
    "results": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "payment_method",
        "defined_in": "option_table",
        "default_option": "5",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Bank Transfer",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Credit Card",
                "value": "5"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "PayPal",
                "value": "8"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
{
    "results": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "invoice_type",
        "defined_in": "class",
        "app_label": "invoices",
        "choices_class": "InvoiceType",
        "default_option": "standard",
        "options": [
            {
                "name": "Standard",
                "value": "standard"
            },
            {
                "name": "Retainer",
                "value": "retainer"
            },
            {
                "order": 1,
                "name": "Estimate",
                "value": "estimate"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The first one (defined_in = "option_table") has its options defined in a related Option model. The second one has its options defined in a subclass of TextChoices in the backend code. In addition to keeping the front/backend in sync for options and default values, this will also allow users to set which option for each select list field they want as the default value. Note the `default_option` field above.

I created a class, extended from the `ChoiceField` class (from DRF), and added logic to the `__init__()` method to get the default value from the OptionGroup model and set it for the serializer field being defined.

```
class CustomChoiceField(serializers.ChoiceField):

    def __init__(self, choices, **kwargs):
        option_group = kwargs.pop('option_group', None)

        if option_group and 'default' not in kwargs:
            group = OptionGroup.objects.filter(name__iexact=option_group)
            if group and group.default_option:
                kwargs['default'] = group.default_option

        super().__init__(choices, **kwargs)
```

And this is how it is being used:

```
    type = CustomChoiceField(
        choices=choices.InvoiceType.choices,
        option_group='invoice_type',
    )
```

The problem is that the active schema at that point is "public" instead of the actual tenant schema. It seems the `__init__()` for my custom class is being executed too early in the request process - before django_tenants has connected to the proper schema.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how this can be accomplished, or is what I'm trying to do just not possible?

Comment: DO you found the solution?

Comment: Not by using a CustomChoiceField class. I ended up writing a ```get_default_option()``` method in the OptionGroup serializer. It worked fine for our needs.